# Dreamweaver FTP issues, changes not taking effect

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver

Ok guys so I've had an ongoing issue, over months where occasionally i'll try to upload a file, it will upload, say's it upload but the changes wont reflect, I'll check code, try different browsers nothing. different computers, nothing. I can physically delete a file, say the index file, and it has no effect, I can still see it in the browser. I run into this issue occasionally and it is such a time killer because it kills my workflow. Now before anyone say's switch away from DW, i can't it's company issue and I'm not in a position to change that now. I've had this issue on CS4 and CS5 and check in 4 different browsers. any ideas?

Comment: Surely you only need to use Dreamweaver to author code? Use a proper FTP program and save yourself _a lot_ of pain.

Answer (score 0):

well first look out for the **settings of your testing server**......check for the auto refresh in the testing server so that the changes u make in your file are updated to your server....as its finally the file in your testing server which get published so look for the files in both the local as well the testing server view>>>>